# Node not loading module from project root

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm beginning some learning projects in node and am having problems with node finding installed modules.

I installed a module into the root directory of a project, which looks like the following:

**C:\Users\Dean\Documents\NodeProjects\ReadWords**

which has my **node_modules** folder and **readwords.js** file I would be running to call the module.

Within node_modules is  **censorify-deanmau5** folder and in there, my various module files.

readwords.js has on line 1

```
var censorify = require('censorify-deanmau5');
```

and in the console when I try to run the file, I get the following:

```
C:\Users\Dean\Documents\NodeProjects\ReadWords>node readwords.js

module.js:340
  throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'censorify-deanmau5'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dean\Documents\NodeProjects\ReadWords\readwo
rds.js:1:79)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

Surely this should be working with having node_modules in the same directory as the .js file I'm trying to run?  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your package](https://github.com/deanmau5/Censorify) seems to have invalid [main](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html#main) entry point. Either rename `censorify.js` as `index.js` or add `"main": "./censorify.js"` to `package.json`.

Comment: adding "main":"./censorify.js" to package.json has worked.  I'm not sure if this would cause problems further down the line should I end up adding more .js files to censorify-deanmau5

Comment: Well, in that configuration `./censorify.js` will work as an entry point. If that module exposes everything correctly, there should be no issues. You can use `npm link` during development to make sure everything is ok. This will allow you to use dev version of the package.